# JAVA: SomeStructure<E> to make it sorted by another type T?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a data class as following:

```
class MyData { private UUID id; private String data1; private String data2}
```

I store its instance in a map:

```
private Map<UUID, MyData> myData;
```

As all we know, I can get MyData instance by UUID:

```
MyData instance = myData.get(UUID);
```

But I also need to get MyData instance by index. What's more, the index is sorted by, say, MyData.data1 field. So I need a new data structure to store UUID according to index order, perhaps something like this:

```
private SomeStructure<UUID> myDataIndex;
```

What I want is this `SomeStructure` class. It should have a public method such as:

```
public UUID getUuidByIndex(int index);
```

And, it should sort UUID elements by MyData.data1 field.

And, every time I put an item to `private Map<UUID, MyData> myData`, the item's UUID is also  added to `private SomeStructure<UUID> myDataIndex`. I think this is a performance consideration, not generating an ArrayList or something else when I get element by index.

Any ideas about this `SomeStructure`? I would appreciate more about a method that extends or implements known JAVA data structure. Of course, fully customized structure is also highly appreciated.

To make you fully understand my question, I'd like to state my situation:

1. why I have Map? I wanna get data by UUID.
2. why I want SomeStructure? I wanna get data by index either.

To make it simple: I want iterate my data through two different ways.

Many thanks!

Comment: I deleted my answer, however I still think the answer may be to use a sorted map, using one of the techniques from [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the techniques from [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) to produce a sorted map that is ordered based on your values.

Once you have such a map, you can access an item using its index with code such as:

```
MyData item = new ArrayList<MyData>(myData.values()).get(index);
```

You can access by its UUID with the normal `get(UUID)`.

Comment: thx for your advice. but i don't agree with you. According to JAVA doc, TreeMap is sorted by KEY, even the comparator is related to KEY but not VALUE: this is its constructor: TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator).

Comment: MyData item = new ArrayList<MyData>(myData.values()).get(index); <-- I think this method is with low performance: every time I get an element by index, should I new an ArrayList? No, I don't think so. This is why I have a "private SomeStructure<UUID> myDataIndex;".

Comment: @McArthorLee Sorry, you are right regarding key sorting. I'll delete this for now.

Comment: @McArthorLee You can try this code and see whether the performance is good enough. I'm not 100% sure what is being done under the covers, it may not be as inefficient as you fear. Don't prematurely optimise either ;-)

Comment: @Duncan, As I see all the solutions (at least the most popular) from the provided thread, sorting a map on its values, is awful in terms of performance: calling map.get(key) twice in __each__ call to `compare`. And the solution is broken too in many cases, see the comments. Well depending on the actual need, I would stick to my solution to build a sorted list as needed. and keep the original map.

Comment: @Duncan thanks, i'll test its performance tomorrow, and give you feedback if i get some result.

Answer (score 0):

Put your element in an `ArrayList<MyData>`:

```
ArrayList<MyData> dataAsList = new ArrayList<>();
dataAsList.addAll(myData.values());

Collections.sort(dataAsList, new Comparator() {
   public int compare(MyData d1, MyData d2) {
      return d1.data1.compareTo(d2.data2);
});

// get the 3rd element
MyData third = dataAsList.get(2);
```

Customise the `Comparator` as you need, for instance if `data1` or `data2` may be null, then some null-checking should be added.

Comment: what if I wanna get data by UUID? I don't wanna iterate the whole ArrayList... sorry for this, I editted my post to try to make my question much clear.

Comment: I did not mean to replace your map. Keep it for access by UUID. You won't have a data structure that does association (key, value) **and** access by index, even with a SortedMap or SortedSet. By the way, I understood you want to sort by _another_ field than the UUID (which is the key). It means you need an additional structure to sort the element the way you want.

Comment: thanks Abbe(France?). i'll check your method tomorrow.

Comment: what about a class that can auto sort when adding element?

Comment: Yes, you can use a `TreeSet` but even if it is sorted, you will need to iterate to get the Nth element. Only `List<T>` interface provides acces by index (aka `get(int i)`).

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying two totally different requirements (search by UUID and access by index in a sorted list), so what you need are two different data structures, i.e. redundant collections:

1. A `Map<UUID, MyData>` for doing lookups by UUID
2. A `List<MyData>` which is sorted by `data1`

Of course, you can - and should - encapsulate both behind a facade to ensure data integrity by controlling access to the underlying data structures:

```
public class MyDataCollection {
    private final Map<UUID, MyData> uuidToDataMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final List<MyData> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();

    /* read-only list */
    public List<MyData> getSortedList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedList);
    }

    /* read-only map */
    public Map<UUID, MyData> getUuidToDataMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(uuidToDataMap);
    }

    public void add(MyData data) {
        if (uuidToDataMap.contains(data.uuid)) {
            // UUID already existing
            // => throw exception, etc.
        }
        uuidToDataMap.put(data.uuid, data);

        // insert into sorted list
        // use binary search to find insertion point (see javadoc)
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(sortedList, data);
        if (index < 0) index = -index - 1; // insertion point
        else index++; // insert after existing element
        sortedList.add(index, data);
    }

    public boolean remove(MyData data) {
        if (uuidToDataMap.remove(data.uuid) == data) {
            sortedList.remove(data);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

*Note: This code example assumes that your `MyData` is `Comparable` by its `data1` field. If that's not the case, a `Comparator` must be implemented and used in `Collections.binarySearch(...)`.*